# How can I load all my keymaps from neovim to vscode with the Vim extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code, lua, neovim

How can I load my keymaps from my init.lua when I use VS Code with the Vim extansion?

I have added init.lua path to Vim extension but it does not load the keymaps

Comment: which vscode vim extention are you talking about? There is vscode-vim and vscode-neovim. Please be specific on what you are asking and edit your post to reflect that.

Comment: Hello @jdhao, thanks you for your comment. I am using the vscode-vim (Vim extenston). I heard the NeoVim extension (vscode-neovim) to be better but needs more configuration so I'm scared to try to set it up.

Comment: I do not think vscode-vim supports init.lua, which is specific to neovim.